issue with a large project using the Mathbook class and the XSIM package
I use the mathbook.cls class by Stéphane Pasquet to create a mathematics book. The book contains 400 pages, 12 chapters, with hundreds of exercises. However, I've encountered two major issues with this class:
On Overleaf: I get the error can't write on file followed by the name of the .tex file corresponding to the solution of an exercise, often 1-1.tex, corresponding to the first exercise of chapter 1.
Locally: It works, and I get the PDF of the book as output, but with many blank pages, and the text of the exercises and solutions overflows the page. Even using \newpage and \BreakCorr doesn't solve the problem. It seems to have a somewhat random behavior.
To work around this, I used the XSIM package, which works both on Overleaf and locally, and provides a correct display. But I encountered another issue: the tex capacity exceeded error. So, I have to compile 2, 3, or 4 chapters maximum at a time, depending on their size.
I had to manually create (and number) the table of contents, then merge the different chapters into a single PDF. This is the best I could do for now, but during this process, I lose the hyperlinks, especially those in the table of contents, and I get funny (higher than normal) page numbers on the PDF reader (not the pages themselves). I used ghostscript to merge the different PDFs. It takes a lot of time to do all this, while normally all should be done in a single compilation (or two for the toc, locally).
Sorry, there can't be any MWE, as it has to be quite large to make the errors appear.
This is it.. Could anyone please help me simplify the compilation process? Thank you

tex normally frees memory as each page is output so you don't get a capacity exceeded from a long document but rather a page with an over compilcated tikz diagram (for example) although the log would show which capacity is exceeded, but you give no information.

It works fine when the chapters are compiled one by one, or by small groups. Could it still be the case?

you need to give at least some information at the very least the error messages from the log. If you are building up memory as the document progresses then why? do you have floats of some sort that are collecting to end document?

It's the XSIM package, I use the exercise and the solution environments for.. exercises and solution, and I have hundreds of them. There's a file called main.xsim that contains all the solutions. And I remember reading that the capacity was exceeded meaning that there are some solutions that are longer than the maximum capacity. But it still works when the chapters are not compiled all at once. The file is too large to copy here.

only mention of capacity exceeded in xsim manual is describing a user error, but as you haven't shown any error message it's impossible to guess

`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
‪./main.tex, 91‬
 ..._A(B)$ veut dire : Parmi les pe\ETC.
l.91 \end{document}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.`
that's the error message, and ETC is where the compilation stopped, it's in chapter 2 only. I got this trying to compile the 12 chapters together.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
